# mapStateToprops is getting called twice and returning an empty array at the end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to store employee data in store using `redux`, but when I tried to access the store using `mapStateToProps` its returning empty array and it is getting called twice. The first time state has the vaue but second time it will return empty array when i inspected it

**reducer/index,js**:

```
    import { AppConstants } from '../constants/actionTypes'
       const initialState = {
          employeeDetails: []
        };
        const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {

          case AppConstants.ADD_EMPLOYEE:
              let emplData = state.employeeDetails
              let data = [
                   ...emplData.slice(0, action.index),
                   action.payload,
                  ...emplData.slice(action.index)
                   ]
            return  {...state,
                  employeeDetails: data
                  }
          default:
                 return state
          }
       }
    export default rootReducer;
```

**`employee.js`**:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
     import Input from '../components/Input'
     import Button from '../components/Button'
     import { addEmployee } from '../actions/index'
      import { connect } from "react-redux";
     class EmployeeForm extends Component {
         constructor(props) {
              super(props);
              this.state = {
               employee: [],
               empName: "",
               empId: "",
               emailId: "",
               empAge: "",

              }
            }


handleChange = (evt) => {
    this.setState({
        [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value
    });

}
handleFormSubmit = () => {
    debugger;
    let employDet = {
        empName: this.state.empName,
        empId: this.state.empId,
        emailId: this.state.emailId,
        empAge: this.state.empAge
    }
    this.props.dispatch(addEmployee(employDet))

}

handleClearForm = () => {

}
handleDelete = (e) => {

}

render() {
    debugger
    let employeeDetails= this.props.employeeDetails
    console.log("in render "+this.props.employeeDetails)
    return (
        <div>
            <form className="container-fluid" >
                <Input
                    inputType={"text"}
                    title={"Full Name"}
                    name={"empName"}
                    value={this.state.empName}
                    placeholder={"Enter your name"}
                    handleChange={this.handleChange}
                />{" "}

                <Input
                    inputType={"text"}
                    title={"Email Id"}
                    name={"emailId"}
                    value={this.state.emailId}
                    placeholder={"Enter your Email Id"}
                    handleChange={this.handleChange}
                />{" "}

                <Input
                    inputType={"text"}
                    title={"Employee Id"}
                    name={"empId"}
                    value={this.state.empId}
                    placeholder={"Enter your Employee Id"}
                    handleChange={this.handleChange}
                />{" "}
                <Input
                    inputType={"number"}
                    name={"empAge"}
                    title={"Age"}
                    value={this.state.empAge}
                    placeholder={"Enter your age"}
                    handleChange={this.handleChange}
                />{" "}


                <Button
                    action={this.handleFormSubmit}
                    type={"primary"}
                    title={"Submit"}
                    className="buttonStyle"
                />{" "}

                <Button
                    action={this.handleClearForm}
                    type={"secondary"}
                    title={"Clear"}
                    className="buttonStyle"
                />{" "}

            </form>
            <br />

            <table border="1" style={{ width: 400, paddingTop: 5 }}>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Employee Name</th>
                        <th>Employee Id</th>
                        <th>Email Id</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {employeeDetails.map((emp, i) => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={i}>
                                <td>{emp.empName}</td>
                                <td>{emp.empId}</td>
                                <td>{emp.emailId}</td>
                                <td>{emp.empAge}</td>
                                {/* <td>
                                    <button onClick={this.handleEdit} id={emp.id}>
                                        Edit
                </button>
                                </td> */}
                                <td>
                                    <button onClick={this.handleDelete} id={emp.emailId}>
                                        Delete
                </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}
}

     const mapStateToProps = state => {

         const { employeeDetails } = state

          return {
               employeeDetails: employeeDetails
          }

         };
        export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EmployeeForm)
```

**`store.js`** :

```
 import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 
 'redux';
 import rootReducer from './reducers/index';
 import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

 const store  = createStore(rootReducer,
                        applyMiddleware(thunk));

 export default store;
```

**`action/index.js`** :

```
   import {AppConstants} from '../constants/actionTypes'


   export const addEmployee = (empData) => {

         return dispatch => {
           dispatch({ type: AppConstants.ADD_EMPLOYEE, 
           payload: empData
         })
      }
   };
```

**ActionType.js **

```
   export const AppConstants = {
        ADD_EMPLOYEE : "ADD_EMPLOYEE",
    }
```

Comment: Please format your code a bit better :)

Comment: Please post source code of './reducers/index', code of your action creator and whole source code of 'employee.js'. This parts are missing for helping you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The main problem** is that you are using form submit button. The standard behaviour of submit button is to submit form and reload browser. Reload in single page app restarts the application from scratch, so you cannot use this standard submit button behaviour. Do not use submit button, e.g. change button type to 'button':

```js
 <button type={'button'} onClick={this.handleFormSubmit}>Submit</button>
```

**The second problem** might be in your reducer. When you are calling push on state.employeeDetails you are mutating it. Try to insert/push new item with immutable operation, redux has some topic on the problem in the documentation:

https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#inserting-and-removing-items-in-arrays

**EDIT:**

In your implementation of suggested redux update pattern you are inserting at specific index (but your action is not sending index now). When you want to just add item to the end (like push, but immutable) you can use array spread operator:

```js
let data = [
  ...emplData,
  action.payload
]
```

Comment: I tried the method used in documentation, but still have the issue. By default reducer called and default state is getting set. I have updated the reducer for reference

Comment: I updated my answer, there was a problem with form submit button.

Comment: Hi. Thank you.. that helped me. The issue was with the <button type as submit.